# Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'cmbY' is not declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am getting a error in this piece of coding,

Line 23:         If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
**Line 24: cmbY.DataSource = rsFirehose("SELECT LeagueTypeKey, LeagueTypeDescription FROM LeagueType " & _**
Line 25:                 "WHERE LeagueTypeKey=0 or (Appkey=" & glngAppKey & " AND LeagueTypeKey IN (SELECT Distinct YKey FROM " & _
Line 26:                 "Division WHERE DivisionTypeKey=" & soaDivisionTypeBracket & ")) ORDER BY LeagueTypeDescription")

**Line 24 is were the error is, it says that the name "cmbY" is not declared, how do i declare it?**

Comment: You have to post more code to clarify the problem

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I really can't tell but it looks as if you are using a custom control that has not has its delecration put on the page header like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="ClickableGridView"%>
```

under the 
<%@ Page ... line